# Why would a specific HttpRequest time out on Android but not other platforms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application for a client, and I am working to integrate calls to a third party REST API into the application. I am able to to POST to the API and get an appropriate response back via Postman.

I wrote some very simple `HttpClient` code to POST to the API, and when I call this code from a Windows console app, it works exactly as intended. However, when I copy and paste this code into my Xamarin.Forms application and run it on an Android device, the `HttpRequest` times out and causes a `TaskCanceledException` to be thrown every single time I try it.

Furthermore, if I take the same code, and change the URL to use a different REST API, it works as intended on both platforms.

It appears that this issue is specific to this particular third party API, but only when the code is running on Android. (I don't have an iOS device to test this at the moment.)

**My question is this:** What could cause the HttpRequest to time out when running on Android from a Xamarin.Forms application, but not when running inside of a Windows console application?

Again, this issue doesn't occur with other API URLs that I have tried, only the one that I need to use for this particular project...

Here is the simplified `HttpClient` code:

```
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var url = "https://third-party-api-url/";
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, null);           // this line throws a TaskCanceledException
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();   // this line is never reached
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // TaskCanceledException is caught here after the HttpClient timeout elapses
}
```

### Here's what I've tried so far...

1. Added the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission to my AndroidManifest.xml
2. Tried using the different HttpClient implementation options in the Advanced Android Options on my Android application project
3. Experimented with using RestSharp versus the stock `HttpClient`
4. I tested on both a physical Android device and the Android Emulator and experienced the same behavior on both.

Comment: It feels like a issue with a firewall or related thing that can block Internet access. Is the app currently allowed to access the internet on the Android device? The default settings might not mater, if there are already current settings that says "deny and do not ask again".

Comment: @Christopher Yes, the app is able to access the Internet on the device. If I just change the URL in the HttpRequest to point to a different web API, it works as expected.